# What is the equivalent of React-Native's createBottomTabNavigator in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend, react-navigation

i'm trying to create a bottom tab navigator that will load in the mobile browser. I only know how to do it in React-Native by using react navigation's [createBottomTabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html). I have no idea what to use for ReactJS for browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

https://material-ui.com/components/bottom-navigation/+

It's suppose that is the same as react native but for reactjs.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no standard tab navigator suggested by ReactJs like React Native for mobile navigation since UI/UX of site is totally different and depends of a lot of factors.

For designing something similar to that although there are lot of 3rd party components with themes & styling are available. I am mentioning some of popular ones', you can try anyone which suits your requirement:

1.react-materialize
  http://react-materialize.github.io/react-materialize/?path=/story/react-materialize--welcome

2. material-ui https://material-ui.com/

3.react-toolbox https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/

4. react-virtualized http://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/List
5. blueprint https://github.com/palantir/blueprint

You can always pick one or more components from some of them & customize them as required.